# mapping jackson with @JsonAnySetter returns Unrecognized field with javassist class

Tags: java, json, jackson, javassist

i'm trying to convert a json string to an object using jackson in a rest WS using jersey on tomcat 8.5.

the object is created at runtime using javassist (with info coming from db) and adding an "other" map annotated with @JsonAnySetter/Getter.

When i call jackson's mapper with buildClass("MyClass"), it throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException`.

When MyClass is already loaded in the classpath at startup without using buildClass, mapping works fine.

i guess there's a Loader issue but i have no clue about solving this.

Kindly review and give feedback.

```
public class ClassFactory{
public Class<?> buildClass(String className){
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
Loader cl = new Loader(pool);

CtClass cc = pool.makeClass(className);
ConstPool constPool = pool.get(className).getClassFile().getConstPool();

/* */
/* field creation loop */
/* */

// other map
CtField field = CtField.make("private java.util.Map other = new java.util.HashMap();", cc);
cc.addField(field);

// add other map getter
CtClass[] paramsAny = {pool.get(String.class.getName())};
cc.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make(pool.get(Object.class.getName()), "any", paramsAny,null, "{ return this.other.get($1);}", cc));
CtMethod m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("any", paramsAny);

// add @JsonAnyGetter to other map getter
AnnotationsAttribute annotationAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag );
annotationAttribute.addAnnotation(new Annotation(JsonAnyGetter.class.getName(), constPool));
m.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(annotationAttribute);

// add other map setter
CtClass[] paramsSet = {pool.get(String.class.getName()), pool.get(Object.class.getName())};
cc.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make(pool.get("void"), "set", paramsSet,null, "{this.other.put($1,$2);}", cc));
m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("set", paramsSet);

// add @JsonAnySetter to other map setter
annotationAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag );
annotationAttribute.addAnnotation(new Annotation(JsonAnySetter.class.getName(), constPool));
m.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(annotationAttribute);

//build class
return cc.toClass(cl,null);
}
}
```

this is a part of the generated class

```
public class MyClass{
/* more fields */

private Map other = new HashMap();
@JsonAnyGetter
public Object any(String var1) {
    return this.other.get(var1);
}
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String var1, Object var2) {
    this.other.put(var1, var2);
}

}
```

the jackson mapper

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader();
Class<?> myClass = new ClassFactory().buildClass("MyClass");
Object myClassInstance =reader.forType(myClass).readValue(jsonString);
```

some json

```
{
    /* more fields */
    "info1":"val1",
    "info2" :"val2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jackson`'s `ClassIntrospector` does not recognize annotation load from `javaassist` class loader. The same class loaded from two different class loaders considered to be different. Try to delegate loading class to parent class loader for these annotations.

```
    Loader cl = new Loader(pool);
    cl.delegateLoadingOf("com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter");
    cl.delegateLoadingOf("com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are missing the setter and getter for the properties "info1" and "info2".

I tested it with below code and the deserialization works fine. Please note the lines where I am adding the setter and getters to the class definition.

```
public class ClassFactory {
    public Class<?> buildClass(String className) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {

        Map<String, Class<?>> properties = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        properties.put("info1", String.class);
        properties.put("info2", String.class);
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        Loader cl = new Loader(pool);

        CtClass cc = pool.makeClass(className);
        ConstPool constPool = pool.get(className).getClassFile().getConstPool();

        CtField field = CtField.make("private java.util.Map other = new java.util.HashMap();", cc);
        cc.addField(field);

// add other map getter
        CtClass[] paramsAny = { pool.get(String.class.getName()) };
        cc.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make(pool.get(Object.class.getName()), "any", paramsAny, null,
                "{ return this.other.get($1);}", cc));
        CtMethod m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("any", paramsAny);

// add @JsonAnyGetter to other map getter
        AnnotationsAttribute annotationAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
        annotationAttribute.addAnnotation(new Annotation(JsonAnyGetter.class.getName(), constPool));
        m.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(annotationAttribute);

// add other map setter
        CtClass[] paramsSet = { pool.get(String.class.getName()), pool.get(Object.class.getName()) };
        cc.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make(pool.get("void"), "set", paramsSet, null, "{this.other.put($1,$2);}", cc));
        m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("set", paramsSet);

// add @JsonAnySetter to other map setter
        annotationAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
        annotationAttribute.addAnnotation(new Annotation(JsonAnySetter.class.getName(), constPool));
        m.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(annotationAttribute);        

        for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            cc.addField(new CtField(resolveCtClass(entry.getValue()), entry.getKey(), cc));
            // add getter
            cc.addMethod(generateGetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            // add setter
            cc.addMethod(generateSetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }

        return cc.toClass(cl, null);
    }

    private static CtMethod generateGetter(CtClass declaringClass, String fieldName, Class fieldClass)
            throws CannotCompileException {

        String getterName = "get" + fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + fieldName.substring(1);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("public ").append(fieldClass.getName()).append(" ")
                .append(getterName).append("(){").append("return this.")
                .append(fieldName).append(";").append("}");
        return CtMethod.make(sb.toString(), declaringClass);
    }

    private static CtMethod generateSetter(CtClass declaringClass, String fieldName, Class fieldClass)
            throws CannotCompileException {

        String setterName = "set" + fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+ fieldName.substring(1);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("public void ").append(setterName).append("(")
                .append(fieldClass.getName()).append(" ").append(fieldName)
                .append(")").append("{").append("this.").append(fieldName)
                .append("=").append(fieldName).append(";").append("}");
        return CtMethod.make(sb.toString(), declaringClass);
    }
    private static CtClass resolveCtClass(Class clazz) throws NotFoundException {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        return pool.get(clazz.getName());
    }


public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, IOException {
        String jsonString = "{ \"info1\":\"val1\", \"info2\" :\"val2\"}";
        ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader();
        Class<?> myClass = new ClassFactory().buildClass("MyClass");
        Object myClassInstance = reader.forType(myClass).readValue(jsonString);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: The entire point of using @JsonAnySetter is to not have to write the individual setters...